# How can I have a JSON file with my current setup?

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py, notepad

My current setup is typing out my discord.py code script in Notepad and using Python 3.9 app to open them as a command prompt. I have a JSON file in a separate Notepad file. Id like to include the JSON file to my code notepad or have it open up with the Python prompt. Ive tried opening them as 2 different Python prompts but it doesnt seem to work. I can explain in more detail to someone who knows how to fix it or needs more explanation on my discord. @Lone Wolf#2245

Answer (score 0):

try using open() and json.loads

You can import dict by using them

```py
from json import loads
dictionary = loads(open('Your file directory', 'r'))
```

Now you can use variable dictionary like dict

Comment: Im still new to coding in python but im making a bank using json. When i will code to open it. How do i write that? Heres part of the bank open.
`async def open_account(user):

    users = await get_bank_data()

    if str(user.id) in users:
        return False
    else:
        users[str(user.id)] = {}
        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0
        users[str(user.id)]["bank"] = 0
        with open("mainbank.json", "w") as f:
          json.dump(users,f)
          return True`

Comment: `async def get_bank_data():
    with open("mainbank.json", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)
    return users`